# Imagine a new color. Imagine a new physical quantity

Tags: perception

It is well known, that a human being can not imagine new colors which are not obtainable by just combining the already known ones (red, green and blue).

Actually I can draw parallels to physics and may ask you: Imagine a new physical quantity, which you must not obtain from simply combining any of the already known ones and without using anything you have ever experienced in your live.

But how would you find a new physical dimension, which you have never experienced in any way? Wouldn't this be like to imagine a new color?

Are we thus somehow bound to never know everything, not because we have too little time or possibilities, but because it literally lies beyond our imagination? *insert dramatic music*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not physics.

Comment: Recommend migration to world-building or philosophy.

Comment: Of course it is physics Hritik. Just on a philosophic level. Migrate it, whatever.

Comment: If it's "on a philosophic level," then it's not physics. [philosophy.se] probably wouldn't take it either, though.

Comment: is there a science fiction SE? It would fit there. Terry Pratchett is great in inventing new physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_of_Magic

Comment: So for example issues of whether there is absolute space is would not be part of physics, because it is philosophy? Or if I make a chemical reaction, it is not physics, because it is chemistry?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta You are talking about human imagination, right? Doesn't *Imagination* pretty clearly leave the scope of real-life physics? Voting to migrate.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: There are some overlaps in sciences, sure. Does that mean that *all* sciences must be asked here? Of course not.

Comment: Why imagine a new color when you can imagine an existing one? http://www.biotele.com/magenta.html Also, we don't have to imagine a new spatial dimension because we already have three that are identical to a new one. Imagine your house has two front doors...

Answer (score 2):

> **It is well known, that a human being can not imagine new colors which are not obtainable by just combining the already known ones (red, green and blue).**

The human imagination, and its capabilities or limits, are not the *subject matter* of Physics.

I happen to think the statement is wrong - I believe I can imagine what infra-red or ultraviolet looks like to creatures that are able to see those wavelengths. My imagination is assisted by viewing infra-red photographs that have been rendered using colour-shift or mapping techniques so that humans may view them.

> **But how would you find a new physical dimension, which you have never experienced in any way?**

Through measurement and mathematics.

There are theories in Physics in which, for example, spacetime is modelled with more than the four classical dimensions. Humans can't directly experience those extra dimensions.

By using those mathematical models to make predictions and making measurements of the observable universe (or of experiments carried out for that purpose) we can "find" new physical dimensions.